# Can every system of linear equations be written in matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

- I know if we have equal number of equation and unknown variables then we can always transform them into matrix form.

For example:

$$ \begin{aligned} 3x - y &= 0 \\ x - 2y &= 3 \end{aligned} $$

Above two can be transformed to

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

But what about the system of equation in which number of unknowns are not same as number of equations. We can make those like:

$$ \begin{aligned} 2x + 3y + 4z - 3 &= 2 \\ 3y + 4z &= 7 \end{aligned} $$

Comment: You can still do it, just it will not be a square matrix.

Comment: You can write a matrix, but the matrix will not be $x \times x$. Matrixes are mathematical objects, and can be diverse in dimension, symmetry etc.

Comment: $$\pmatrix{2&3&4\cr0&3&4\cr}\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr z\cr}=\pmatrix{5\cr7\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks i got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System of finite linear equations, with finite number of variables, can be understand as linear transformation between some finite dimensional vector spaces.

Suppose we have $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{V}$ vector spaces over the same field and $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n \}$ and $\{y_1,\cdots,y_m \}$ are bases of $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{V}$ respectively. Corresponding matrix $A$ is, by definition, rectangular, $m$ by $n$, and defined by
$$Ax_j=\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_{ij}y_i$$
where $\alpha_{ij}$ are scalars from mentioned field.

So, matrix theory can be extend to linear transformations, i.e. systems of linear equations, and vise versa.

Comment: So if we have finite number of equations  & variables then it can always be transformed into matrix. It doesn't matter if both of them are equal or not?

Did i got your point correctly?

Comment: also what does ut mean by vector spaces on same field. Sorry i am quite new to this.

Comment: Yes to your 1-st and second questions. Vector spaces you can find here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space and/or in, for example, P.R. Halmos - Finite-dimensional vector spaces-Springer-Verlag (1974) or Springer(1987). What I wrote is slightly changed text from 1974 edition, pages 70-71, point 19.